# How to fix this streaming color bitcoin ticker using awk?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, bitcoin

I found the following command which implement a live Bitcoin Ticker with awk on the Linux Console. The command use transactions data from a irc channel #bitcoin-market irc.freenode.net and give a green, black or red indication if Bitcoins rise or fall.

```
tail -f ~/.xchat2/scrollback/FreeNode/\#bitcoin-market.txt | awk '/mtgox.*USD/{if (last<$9) { c=32 } else if ( last>$9) { c=31 } else { c=30 }; if ($7>10) { b=";7"} else if ($7>2) { b=";4"} else { b="" }; ; printf "\033[1;" c "m%s mtgoxUSD %8s @ %-8s\033[0m\n", $5,$7,$9; last=$9 }'
```

Unfortunately the Transaction format in the IRC Channel changed since the original author posted the command. On some Transaction lines there is a extra column "x15 x11"

```
<amphipod> Jan08 20:18:23 bitstamp          1.9808 @   816.94       USD
<amphipod> Jan08 20:17:55 mtgox     x15    11.1083 @   934.42352057 USD
<amphipod> Jan08 20:17:58 mtgox             0.1029 @   560.00       GBP
<amphipod> Jan08 20:18:23 bitstamp          0.0010 @   815.00       USD
<amphipod> Jan08 20:18:29 kraken            0.4942 @   607.00       EUR
<amphipod> Jan08 20:18:02 mtgox     x11     6.4768 @   927.39960916 USD
```

How can I adapt the command above to ignore that information in the extra column?

The original author describe the structure of the command in the following video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HLnyDsr-4Ak

Answer (score 1):

The new column causes all columns from the 5th to be shifted to the right. So you can change all values of `$5`, `$7`, ... to `$6`, `$8`, and so on, like this:

```
awk '/mtgox.*USD/{if (last<$10) { c=32 } else if ( last>$10) { c=31 } else { c=30 }; if ($8>10) { b=";7"} else if ($8>2) { b=";4"} else { b="" }; ; printf "\033[1;" c "m%s mtgoxUSD %8s @ %-8s\033[0m\n", $6,$8,$10; last=$10 }'
```

The `awk` one-liner expanded nicely:

```
/mtgox.*USD/ {
    if (last < $10) { c = 32 }
    else if (last > $10) { c = 31 }
    else { c = 30 }
    if ($8 > 10) { b = ";7" }
    else if ($8 > 2) { b = ";4"}
    else { b = "" }
    printf "\033[1;" c "m%s mtgoxUSD %8s @ %-8s\033[0m\n", $6, $8, $10
    last = $10 
}
```

Save it in `ticker.awk`, and you can call it with:

```
tail -f ~/.xchat2/scrollback/FreeNode/\#bitcoin-market.txt | awk -f ticker.awk
```

**UPDATE**

If you want the script to work for other lines too without the `x??` values, you could filter the input. For example, if the 5th column starts with "x", exclude it, and then use the original script, like this:

```
tail -f ~/.xchat2/scrollback/FreeNode/\#bitcoin-market.txt | awk '$5 ~ /^x/ { $5="" }1' | awk '/mtgox.*USD/{...}'
```

Comment: That works for all lines where the extra colum is added. But in some Ticker lines there is no extra column. So I need a distinction for the lines with x11 x15 and without.

Comment: @OliverG. Use `NF-#` instead of hard-coding the field numbers?

Comment: @OliverG. I updated my post with another alternative

Answer (score 1):

Just access the first 4 fields as numbers `1 -> 4` and the last 4 as `NF-3 -> NF` in your script:

```
$ cat file
<amphipod> Jan08 20:18:23 bitstamp          1.9808 @   816.94       USD
<amphipod> Jan08 20:17:55 mtgox     x15    11.1083 @   934.42352057 USD
<amphipod> Jan08 20:17:58 mtgox             0.1029 @   560.00       GBP
<amphipod> Jan08 20:18:23 bitstamp          0.0010 @   815.00       USD
<amphipod> Jan08 20:18:29 kraken            0.4942 @   607.00       EUR
<amphipod> Jan08 20:18:02 mtgox     x11     6.4768 @   927.39960916 USD

$ awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $(NF-3), $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF}' file
<amphipod> Jan08 20:18:23 bitstamp 1.9808 @ 816.94 USD
<amphipod> Jan08 20:17:55 mtgox 11.1083 @ 934.42352057 USD
<amphipod> Jan08 20:17:58 mtgox 0.1029 @ 560.00 GBP
<amphipod> Jan08 20:18:23 bitstamp 0.0010 @ 815.00 USD
<amphipod> Jan08 20:18:29 kraken 0.4942 @ 607.00 EUR
<amphipod> Jan08 20:18:02 mtgox 6.4768 @ 927.39960916 USD
```

So change `$7` in your original script to `$(NF-1)` for example.